# Should I try to standardize the location of help buttons?

Tags: layout, help, dashboard

I've created a dashboard containing a map. My client wants little help buttons on each of the panels so if the user has a question about what something my do in each panel, they can click and see an explanation as well as more information about what actions can be performed in each panel.

Currently, I just have the buttons in a non-intrusive area of each panel (see mockup). Should I try to standardize their location (put them all in the same corner of each panel) or is having them in different areas acceptable?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### **Make them consistent**.

If a user has discovered it once, you don't want to make them work to find it again. Ideally, you wouldn't need any help buttons at all. Your panels should be self explanatory and how they work should be obvious to your users at first glance.

Having said that some complex interfaces require a small amount of learning, and help text can help users to get going. But try to work it into the interface, rather than hidden behind a button.

Answer (score 2):

Yes of course . Consistency and repeatability of the help contents are key to good user experience.  For the users, make sure you devise ways for him to think that there is a place or location on the interface where he can get all the information that he needs.

Besides, you could also add in a "Hover help (tooltips)", i.e When users place the cursor over a user interface object such as field or button, a tooltip appears explaining the purpose of that object and offers brief help in how to use it.

This feature will be most useful if the task she/he is doing has a fair bit of complexity surrounding it. If you over do, the user might perceive the system as being patronising.

Most important is that the help you provide is context sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, for all six gray panels,

you must put the tool-tip button,

at the **top right**.